# Can the Macbook be woke while closed?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I set a schedule wakeup in the energy preferences. It doesn't seem to wake up. Is the Macbook capable of waking up, turning on wifi and then running cron jobs while shut?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. Why do you need to awake your **MacBook** while the lid is closed? And why do you need to close the lid at all if you aren't transporting it anywhere outside your room? Leave the lid open if you aren't in moving. And your problem is solved.

You will get more from this link: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2208013?tstart=0

Hope this helps ☺️

Comment: I figured if I forgot, and shut it

Comment: You can use a program called **Insomnia** to keep it awake when the lid is closed and then I think the scheduler will override that and shut it down/wake it up. That's a possible solution. But the program isn't recommended by any of the trusted source.

_Be careful about keeping the lid closed with it on though. Heat is dissipated through the keyboard and can cause the temperature to rise when closed._